# how to allow custom php file to direct access in joomla 3.9?

Tags: php, joomla

Forms has been built inside article which will access outside the php file of joomla. If I disable htaccess it is working but if I enable I cant access the custom php file. Is there any option to allow this file alone in htaccess

```
<form action="form_submit.php">
<input hidden="return_url" value="">
</form>
\\should be submit and redirect to article url
//http://example.com/form_submit.php giving 500 server error
```

Comment: You can put your PHP file in a sub folder which has it's own htaccess, overriding the main one.

Comment: http://example.com/membership/form_submit.php giving 500 error

Comment: Then it seems like you have some error in your PHP file. Check your servers error log and see what the error message actually is. If you're working locally, then I would recommend enabling `display_errors`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes you are right i can echo hi and exit file is working. Could you please show me how to add custom php file in joomla

Comment: If run echo in your file and it worked, then you already successfully added a custom PHP file in joomla. You must have some PHP error in it if you get a 500 error. Like I said, you need to find out what that error is and you need to add the code of that file into your question, if you want us to be able to help.